# Jackson-dataformat-xml produces unexpected results when compared to other libraries

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm evaluating tools for converting xml string to Json in Java.

I'm having issue with jackson (jackson-data-format-xml:2.8.8)

Here is my sample XML stored in String value: `xmlString`:

```
        <books>
          <book>
            <author>Robert Marin</author>
            <title>Clean code</title>                
          </book>
          <book>
            <author>Donald Knuth</author>
            <title>Concrete Mathematics</title>
          </book>
        </books>
```

Using, org.json:json:20140107 jar, I've come up with the following code:

```
XML.toJSONObject(xmlString).toString(2);
```

The output is as expected:

```
{
 "books": {
   "book": [
     {
      "author": "Robert Marin",
      "title": "Clean code"
     },
     {
      "author": "Donald Knuth",
      "title": "Concrete Mathematics"
     }
  ]
 }
}
```

However, When I'm using XmlMapper provided by Jackson library, the output is way different (and simply wrong!):`new XmlMapper().readTree(xmlString).toString()` produces the following JSON:

```
{"book":{"author":"Donald Knuth","title":"Concrete Mathematics"}}
```

So my question is: How should I achieve the same results (in terms of json semantics, I care less about the formatting, indentations and so forth) with Jackson library?

Thanks a lot for the help in advance

Comment: I've found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872489/jackson-xmlmapper-xml-to-json-conversion-issue And apparently using another library (just like I did) works - but I would like to what jackson-dataformat-xml can offer as well, I don't believe it can't handle pretty simple XMLs like this.

Comment: Hang around on StackOverflow for a while, and nothing will surprise you any more when it comes to expectations of software quality.

Comment: See if this might be helpful https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/187. However, you can always deserialize the XML to an object (new XmlMapper().readValue()) and then serialize to JSON.

Comment: It's hardly unexpected when it's mentioned as a [known limitation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml#known-limitations). Also JSON output of `org.json` you mention doesn't correspond to XML. `books` should be an array and `book` shouldn't exist in the JSON